# $P(A \cap A)=1$ but when calculating p-value, it doesnt work

Tags: probability, statistics

I have in my book the following expression from a p-value $$p=P(|T| \geq |t|)=2P(T \leq -|t|)$$

I tried evaluating it and I got the following $$p=P(|T| \geq |t|)=P(-|T| \leq t\leq |T|) = P(-|T| \leq t \text{ and } t\leq |T|)$$
by absolute value rules. Then I rewrite it $$ P(-|T| \leq t \text{ and } t\leq |T|)=P((-|T| \leq t) \cap (t\leq |T|))=P((|T| \geq t) \cap (t\leq |T|))=1$$

since we know that $P(A \cap A)=1$.

> what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot a minus for $t$ in the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that
$$ P(|T|\ge |t|)=P(\{T\ge |t|\} \cup \{T\le -|t|\})=P(\{T\ge |t|\}) + P(\{T\le -|t|\}), $$
by symmetry of $T$ around $0$, you have that $P(\{T\ge |t|\}) = P(\{T\le -|t|\})$, thus
$$ P(|T|\ge |t|)=2P(\{T\le -|t|\}). $$

Comment: how did you do the first step? How do you know that $|T| \geq |t|=(T \ge |t| ) \cup (T \leq -|t|)$?

Comment: $T$ is a random variable with symmetric pdf around $0$ which supported on $\mathbb{R}$,  while $t$ is your calculated statistic. Hence the event $\{|T|\le |t|\}$ can happen when $T$ is greater than $|t|$ or less than its symmetric value $-|t|$.

Comment: thank you. ANother thing: why can we do $$P(\{T\ge |t|\} \cup \{T\le -|t|\})=P(\{T\ge |t|\}) + P(\{T\le -|t|\}), $$
? Is it because they are independent?

Comment: No, it is because ther are disjoint events, i.e., $ \{T>|t|\} \cap \{T<|t|\} = \emptyset$. If you are bothered with the equality then recall that $T$ is continuous r.v., thus $P(T=c)=0$.